# Concatenate a range of cells with a comma

Tags: google-sheets

I'd like to combine a range of cells of data so that it comes out with just one text string and a comma + space between each one. I have been successful in using concatenate:

```
=ArrayFormula(concatenate(C3:F&", "))
```

but there are extra commas that don't need to be there in between some data and a lot of extra commas at the end.

[Example Sheets](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1lHfyuR7r8xJmSPlUAa5bLAn7a7728KLNxmPl-UkYzTg/edit#gid=0).

Answer (score 134, accepted):

A easy way (if you don't have that many columns) would be to use a literal array and filter out the empty cells with query. Something like this

```
=join(", ", query({C3:C; D3:D; E3:E; F3:F}, "where Col1 <>''"))
```

Also see cell A1 in the spreadsheet you shared.

UPDATED:
An alternative (and shorter) way would be to use textjoin()

```
=textjoin(", ", 1, C2:F)
```

Comment: I had to use ; instead of , so it was =textjoin(", "; 1; c2:f)

Comment: @sigmapi13: the use of semi-colons/comma's depends on the locale of the user.

Comment: +1 for the TEXTJOIN (https://support.google.com/docs/answer/7013992?hl=en) approach. Simple and effective. (I'd suggest, for the 2nd parameter, using `true` instead of `1`, as it's more explicit/readable.)

Answer (score 2):

To prevent the delimiter doubling when there's a blank cell in the column, use

```
=JOIN(",", QUERY(A:A, "SELECT A WHERE A IS NOT NULL"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also `concat` twice, with another column containing just a comma with spacing

|  | A | B | C | D | E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | x | , | p |  |  |
| 2 | y | , | q |  |  |
| 3 | z | , | r |  |  |

In D `=ArrayFormula(concat(A1:A,B1:B)` which will get x, 
In E `=ArrayFormula(concat(D1:D,C1:C)` which will get x, p 
You can now hide column D

Answer (score -1):

For mine, I had a single number in each multiple cells which I wanted to combine into a single cell separated by a comma then a space.  I used `"=Concatenate (B2,"' ",B3,"' ",B4,"' ",B5,"' ",B6,"' ",B7,"' ",B8...)`, etc. It worked like a charm! Just type out all your cell names w/o anything in between, then use your arrow keys to advance the pointer, then paste ,`"' "`, between each one!

Answer (score -3):

It can be as simple as `=concatenate(A1, " ", B2, " ", C2, ...)`