# Concatenate a range of cells with a comma and replace empty cell with 0

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I benefited a lot from this post

[Concatenate a range of cells with a comma](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41125877/concatenate-a-range-of-cells-with-a-comma)

On top of concatenating, is it possible for me to replace those empty cell with 0 in one line of command?

E.g. Can I get 1,0,4, from the following table in one line of command?

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 |  | 4 |

The post above taught me two commands, but they are not helpful. Notice

```
=ArrayFormula(concatenate(A1:C3&","))
```

will give 1,,4,

while

```
=textjoin(",", 1, A1:C3)
```

will give 1,4,

(I am aware that there are ways to fill blank with zero beforehand, but I have a lot to work with so it wouldn't be efficient.)

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with

```
arrayformula(if(isblank(A1:C3),0,A1:C3))
```

and use concatenate or other functions you need from there

```
concatenate(arrayformula(if(isblank(A1:C3),0,A1:C3)&","))
```

gives 1,0,4, for example

Comment: Thank you very much!! I cannot do upvote since I am newly registered. This is very useful!

Answer (score 0):

Could also try

```
=substitute(substitute(textjoin(",",false,A1:O1),",,",",0,"),",,",",0,")
```

or

```
=substitute(substitute(regexreplace(textjoin(",",false,A1:1),",*$",""),",,",",0,"),",,",",0,")
```